# What would cause an infinite redirect on the /group route?

Tags: python, ckan

I'm running CKAN 2.6.3 locally on my mac. I've tried replicating this instance from a database dump on the remote instance. The rest of the site seems to work just fine, but hitting /group leads to an infinite redirect.

If I try and visit a specific group, I can view that just fine.
Adding a group gives me the following stack trace.

`IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "group_name_key" DETAIL: Key (name)=() already exists. 'INSERT INTO "group" (id, name, title, type, description, image_url, created, is_organization, approval_status, state, revision_id) VALUES (%(id)s, %(name)s, %(title)s, %(type)s, %(description)s, %(image_url)s, %(created)s, %(is_organization)s, %(approval_status)s, %(state)s, %(revision_id)s)' {'description': u'', 'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 8, 19, 57, 57, 297647), 'title': u'', 'approval_status': u'approved', 'is_organization': False, 'state': u'active', 'image_url': u'', 'revision_id': u'339d9b92-cfc3-4a0b-9bb7-cd8e53f15f62', 'type': u'group', 'id': 'a827e08b-9afd-4e3a-98c3-a78e4247b377', 'name': u''}`

Having followed a few troubleshooting paths, I've come up dry, except discovering that the initial request to /group serves a 301 redirect back to /group.

Other tidbits:

- The remote instance does not have the same issue running under the
  paster httpserver
- Locally served with the standard paster httpserver
  with `paster serve /etc/ckan/development.ini`
- I also can't add
  datasets. As I'm just discovered while posting this. Looks to me like
  a related error. (stacktrace posted below)

`IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (b7b54c05-cbb7-4f15-ac05-2d8caf442eb4, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0c61de41-bd40-4f7a-b639-16a2f2aea503, null, null, null, null, active, dataset, null, f, 2018-07-09 03:08:37.42187, null, 2018-07-09 03:08:37.421862). 'INSERT INTO package (id, name, title, version, url, author, author_email, maintainer, maintainer_email, notes, license_id, type, owner_org, creator_user_id, metadata_created, metadata_modified, private, state, revision_id) VALUES (%(id)s, %(name)s, %(title)s, %(version)s, %(url)s, %(author)s, %(author_email)s, %(maintainer)s, %(maintainer_email)s, %(notes)s, %(license_id)s, %(type)s, %(owner_org)s, %(creator_user_id)s, %(metadata_created)s, %(metadata_modified)s, %(private)s, %(state)s, %(revision_id)s)' {'maintainer': None, 'name': None, 'metadata_modified': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 9, 3, 8, 37, 421870), 'title': None, 'url': None, 'notes': None, 'owner_org': None, 'private': False, 'maintainer_email': None, 'author_email': None, 'state': u'active', 'version': None, 'author': None, 'creator_user_id': None, 'license_id': None, 'revision_id': u'0c61de41-bd40-4f7a-b639-16a2f2aea503', 'type': u'dataset', 'id': 'b7b54c05-cbb7-4f15-ac05-2d8caf442eb4', 'metadata_created': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 9, 3, 8, 37, 421862)}`

My hunch is that there is some corrupt data, either a dataset or a group, that has a null name value, and then subsequently the name isn't being passed correctly.

[Here's the config, with certain details omitted partially or entirely.](https://gist.github.com/LukeTully/6d4ce1dac0b89760bb5cf4a55942bcb6)

Comment: Have you confirmed if the same issue exists in the latest release (2.8.0)?

Comment: Have not. I need to do an upgrade anyway, so will try to isolate that. Again, it does seem to only occur on my local machine on the same version as the remote instance. The remote instance seems to handle the route just fine.

Comment: The null name values are screwy - somewhere between the form, schema and other IDataset / IGroup plugins this info is getting lost. You're running with paster so you may be find out what causes the redirect by a) Increase the log level in your config: [logger_ckan]
level = DEBUG b) putting print statements into ckan/controllers/group.py:GroupController.read ; but I can't see any redirects in this area tbh.

Comment: @DRead I'll try increasing the log level. Otherwise I've set up a proper breakpoint based debugger with PyCharm. I've been able to follow program execution up to line 190 in create.py at which point model.Session.flush() is called and kills it. Up until this point, the form data seems to be coming through just fine.

Comment: @DRead The dataset issue turned out to be an incorrect indent in create.py. Not sure how that happened. I haven't had any look on the group redirect issue. It doesn't work on a fresh install, 2.8, no plugins, fresh config, nothing. There has to be some key difference between my local setup and remote that I'm just not seeing.